# parameter passing with jumi

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, jumi

I have a problem about passing parameter with jumi. In my normal php code i passed it like this

```
<a href=\"editdata_form.php?isbn=$row[isbn]\"> Edit </a>
```

the $row[isbn] is an integer value which putting in isbn variable and send it to "editdata_form.php" page where i get that value with $_GET['isbn'].

In jumi i want to pass this kind of data from a module (custom jumi module) to a article page. For that when i using this code for transferring the data like

```
<a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=18?isbn=$row[isbn]\"> Edit </a>
```

it shows an error like "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

So, in jumi what is the appropriate way to pass data from one module to another article page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo in your querystring.  The ? should be &:

```
<a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=18&isbn=$row[isbn]\"> Edit </a>
                                                                   ^
```

And not clear if this is your actual code, so further changes might include some varation of this:

```
<a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=18&isbn=<?php echo $row[isbn] ?>\"> Edit </a>
```

Comment: At least i got it. It is all about the link where i want to pass the data of. The "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&It.....blaa blaaa" is a not SEO user friendly link. After change it to SEO friendly from joomla global config, IT turn into index,php\edit.....and it works...............:)
By the way thanks for your comment. :)

Comment: Cool...so not sure if my answer should be accepted or not, but happy to help :)